# How to check the load capacity of a telegram bot?

Tags: python, performance, testing, telegram-bot

I made a telegram bot in python and before launching I want to check how SQLite will react if about 50 people send commands at the same time.

First of all, can you please tell me how to test the load capacity if the bot is running directly on my computer?

I tried Jmeter but unfortunately I couldn't figure it out and did not see a clear explanation anywhere